# Web App Layout is wrong when deployed on linux via LAN

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-applications

I want to run an simple web application on my industrial PC (based on raspberrypi) and host it on LAN. The purpose of the web application is that there is some kind of interface for the PC via WiFi. The PC has Debian OS running (without a graphical interface).

I made the ASP.NET Core Web Application on Windows with Visual studio 2019. When I run the application in visual studio, it all looks OK:

[image: On Windows]

In order to run the app on Linux, I published the app (Self contained, Single File, linux-arm). On the PC I have configured some routes using iptables. I opened port 443 (HTTPS) and 80 (HTTP) to allow browser traffic through these ports. Both the ethernet and WiFi have a static IP. When I run the app, and browse to the page on another device via LAN the layout or something is all messed up. I don't know where to start because I have little to none experience with ASP.NET/ HTML / CSS.

[image: On Linux PC via LAN]

I Also tried hosting it on Nginx, but i had the same result.

Can someone please help?:)

Comment: It looks like your CSS isn't loading. Note that the correct tag for ASP.NET Core is `[asp.net-core]` not `[asp.net]` and `[core]` (the latter refers to CPU cores and threading).

Comment: I suggest you open your browser's debugger (in Chrome you can do so by pressing F12), head on over to the Network tab, and reload your page. It should tell you what files failed to load and where it expects to find them.

Comment: But why should it load when I run it on Windows, but not on Linux? The site.CSS file is included into the wwwroot folder

Comment: Maybe you hardcoded `http://localhost/css/style.css` in your header template rather than a path relative to the host? There's no way I can tell - only you have the tools and ability to debug this.

Comment: Yep, got a 404 CSS files. Don't know why, but it looks like the path isn't correct.

Comment: Compare the URL to that when it works locally. Is it the same other than the host?

Comment: https://ibb.co/BwbDhr9

Comment: _"I published the app (Self contained, Single File, linux-arm)"_ - that doesn't include your wwwroot folder.

Comment: If you click on one of the failed requests (e.g. `site.css`) another pane should appear. You can then click on "Headers" and you should see the "Request URL" under "General". Repeat this for your linux-hosted code and your local enivronment code. Compare.

Comment: Ah, it sounds like you have the answer then @CodeCaster.

Comment: When I run it on Windows the the index is 'HTTPS://localhost:44376' and on Linux 'HTTPS://192.168.10.1/' (Static IP), The port is 433. Do you have any idea how to hardcore the paths of these files?

Comment: @CodeCaster So the problem is self-contained or single file?

Comment: I just think that you didn't deploy the wwwroot directory. Can you confirm that you did?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a couple of years too late, additionally this might not be the specific cause of your problem as there could be multiple causes to this.

I had the exact same symptoms when I attempted to run this from the terminal from my home directory. Just changing my directory to the root directory of the site and the css, js, images and so on started working again. I think it was looking for those files in my home directory rather than the executables directory. So this is one cause which might help someone.